# Select the orders placed in 1996-1997 by customers from Brazil SQL(pgAdmin4) to MongoDB

Tags: sql, mongodb

--I have a collection named "orders" and in its documents I have attributes "_id",
"o_clerk", o_comment", "o_custkey" , "o_orderkey", "o_orderdate", "o_totalprice","o_orderstatus", "o_shippriority", "o_orderpriority". "o_orderdate" is is written like this: "o_orderdate" : "1993-08-24". I want to resolve this question from SQL(pgAdmin4) to MongoDB: select the orders placed in 1996-1997 by customers from Brazil. Here is the SQL query for that:

--first I extract the year from the date of placing the order (o_ordered)

```
SELECT DISTINCT EXTRACT (YEAR FROM o_orderdate )
 FROM orders
 ORDER BY 1
```

-- then I continued with this part

```
SELECT o_orderkey, c_name AS customer_name, n_name,
    SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT (YEAR FROM o_orderdate ) = 1996 THEN o_totalprice ELSE 0 END ) AS orders_1996,
    SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT (YEAR FROM o_orderdate ) = 1997 THEN o_totalprice ELSE 0 END ) AS orders_1997
 FROM customer 
INNER JOIN orders ON c_custkey=o_custkey 
INNER JOIN nation ON n_nationkey=c_nationkey 
WHERE n_name='BRAZIL'
GROUP BY o_orderkey, c_name, n_name
ORDER BY 1
```

--In MongoDB I started writing like that:

```
function parse_date(year) {
year = obj['o_orderdate'].getFullYear();
month = obj['o_orderdate'].getMonth() + 1;
day = obj['o_orderdate'].getUTCDate();
printjson(year);
}
db.orders.find({"_id":
ObjectId("5fb6c08fb8065357ba4fb514"),"o_orderdate":{"$gt":new
Date("1998-01-15")}},{
"o_orderdate":1}).forEach(parse_date)
```

--I don't know how to do this query in MongoDB.

Comment: Please provide some sample data of MongoDB

Comment: I posted below, thanks for the help!

Comment: Please update your question instead of writing the information as an answer. Also this is a query (which is also fine) but no sample data. NB, when you migrate an application from Oracle to MongoDB then it is typically a bad design if you migrate the tables one-by-one to a collection. NoSQL databases are not optimized for joins (some NoSQL databases do not support joins at all), the number of MongoDB collections is usually **much lower** than the number of tables in according Oracle.

Comment: So how can I write:   SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT (YEAR FROM o_orderdate ) = 1996 THEN o_totalprice ELSE 0 END ) AS orders_1996 in MomgoDB